# Cannot debug Karma tests in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, karma-runner, webstorm

I have been looking for a few days around the Internet in order to find an answer but, so far, haven't found anything.

So here's my problem: I cannot debug Karma tests or my app.

I am developing on a CentOS 6.7 a web app with WebStorm 10.0.4
I am using TypeScript and Angular, and use Karma for unit tests and Protractor for e2e tests. I managed to set the Protractor debuging, which means I can set some breakpoints over my tests code and it will pause on it.

I am using Firefox 38.0.0 (can't use an other version). Chrome is not installed.
I've set a **Karma run configuration** and a **Remote Firefox configuration**.

---

#### Karma problems

When I *run* my Karma tests, it's all good. But when I want to *debug* them, I've got the following message:

**No supported browser found

JavaScript debugging is currently supported in Chrome or Firefox**.

#### App debugging problems

It's even worse : when I launch the remote firefox debugging, everything is fine until I put a breakpoint in WebStorm: then the app just freeze and I can't do anything.

---

What am I missing ? Is there more configuration to do ?
Your help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If you are still looking for the solution here is my solution:

1. I think debugging in WebStorm is only possible with Chrome. At least I couldn't find any word about firefox anymore.
2. After installing Chrome and JetBrains extension open settings of the WebStorm. Select Tools => Web Browsers and enable Chrome.

Since I did step 2, debugging was possible.

Hope it helps you too.